# Given a feature vector, how to find whether my data points are linearly separable

Tags: machine-learning, classification, supervised-learning

I have a feature vector in matrix notation, and I have data points in 2D plane. How to find whether my data points are linearly separable with that feature vector?

One can check whether there exists a line divides the data points into two. If there isn't a line, how to check for linear separability in higher dimensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### A theoretical answer

If we assume the samples of the two classes are distributed according to a Gaussian, we will get a quadratic function describing the decision boundary in the general case.

If the covariance matrices are identical we get a linear decision boundary.

### A practical answer

See the [SO discussion here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9779179/1864294).

Comment: Thank you, It is very much helpful.