# How can I say if I can divide 2 groups of points with a line?

Tags: algorithm

What is the algorithm to tell if I can divide an array of points with a line?

```
Input: array of (x ,y, TYPE)   # TYPE in (0, 1)
Output: True/False
```

Or how can I say if it's not possible? When 1 (or more) point is always somewhere in the other group of points.

[image]

Comment: Can't you always? Could you clarify?

Comment: No, you can have such points that you can't draw a line where left side contains only TYPE 0 points and right side has only TYPE 1 points.

Comment: Construct convex hulls separately for type1 and type2 points and check if they intersect.

Comment: The second example is lineary separable in *polar coordinates*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Determine whether the two classes are linearly separable (algorithmically in 2D)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9779179/determine-whether-the-two-classes-are-linearly-separable-algorithmically-in-2d)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some crazy ideas:

- Build a "convex hull" for every point set (see for example 
  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graham_scan). And then check if that
  two convex hulls intersecting or not. If not intersecting than
  (fairly, i'm not sure) the answer is YES (the separating line
  exists).
- Use simplest neural network with single neuron (perceptron). It does exactly the needed task - do linear separaton of two sets. The decision of separation line existance can be made by network error function value on the given set of points.